# I need to fill the data in one xlsx file to another xlsm file using Python xlwings, Pandas, numpy ... I am new to Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlwings

I am new to Python. I want to automate manual Excel tasks. Please help me.

I have one master xlsm file and another xlsx file with multiple sheets.

I am taking the values from multiple sheets in xlsx file and filling required cells in xlsm file.

Master xlsm file contains:

```
Item no, Item Name, Jan              
10,       aaa,      data_to_be_filled
20,       bbb,      data_to_be_filled
30,       ccc,      data_to_be_filled
```

Source xlsx file:

```
Item no, Item Name, Amount
10,       aaaa       1000
20,       bbbb       2000
30,       cccc       3000
```

I want the amount column data to be filled in corresponding cells in Master file 'Jan' column.

Edit, I tried the following:

```
pd.read_excel. df1 = pd.read_excel(master_file, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=52) 
df2 = pd.read_excel(source_file, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=2)
Left_join = pd.merge(df1, df2, on ='Item no.', how ='left') 
right_join = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'Item no.', how='right') 
left_right_join = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on = 'Item no.', right_on='Item no.', how='right') 
inner_join = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'Item no.', how='inner') 
outer_join = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Item no.', how='outer')
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: You can delete the code here in the comments, I've added it to your question. Now, once `Item name` is `aaa` and then `aaaa`, typo or intended?

Comment: Intended... even the item no is not there in source. I have I added it manually. otherwise dynamic operation is not possible.

Comment: right_join = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'Item no.', how='right')  this right join is working. but after that I do not know how to assign the value to master cell.
Is there any other method available to fill the cells? Could anyone help me please.

Comment: I posted an answer, please check and give feedback. But next time, please also post something like "expected output". This mostly helps more than most descriptions. And as easier to understand as faster you're getting a answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

```
df_final = pd.merge(df1, df2[["Item no", "Amount"]], on="Item no", how="left")
df_final["Jan"] = df_final["Amount"]
df_final.drop("Amount", axis=1, inplace=True)
```

****Output:****

```
    Item no Item Name   Jan
0   10      aaa         1000
1   20      bbb         2000
2   30      ccc         3000
```

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for your answer.

I solved with following code.

```
list_item_no = [10,20,30...]
x = 0
y = 0

def item_no_in_source_file():
    for item_no in list_item_no:
        for row_source in range(1,55):
            for col_source in range(1, 10):
                if ws2.range((row_source,col_source)).value == item_no:                                   
                    ns_col = 2  
                    global x, y
                    x = item_no
                    y = (int(round(ws2.range(row_source, ns_col).value)))
                    item_no_in_master_file(x, y)
                else:
                    continue


def item_no_in_master_file(a, b):    
        for row in range(1, 200): 
            for col in range(0, 2):                
                if ws1.range((row,col)).value == a:
                    jan_col = 2
                    ws1.range(row, jan_col).value = y
                else:
                    continue


item_no_in_source_file()
```

Comment: Format the answer properly. This is always important, but especially with Python.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't understand the full idea of the code, but looping over a dataset is mostly not best pracitce. If it's just a small dataset it might be fine, but if the data gets bigger it'll become very slow. And if you want to learn Python and you're at the beginning, than don't get used to anything that will handicap you later.

Comment: I formatted my code. But Marco's answer is the right approach.  Thanks Marco once again.

Comment: Hi @Marco_CH, how to fill the cell values of column 'Jan' in master file from df_final["Jan"] using xlwings instead of exporting to new file.